# find the most common hour (from 0 to 23)

Tags: python, dataframe

If I've a sheet has a data like these:

```
Start Time,End Time,Trip Duration,Start Station,End Station,User Type,Gender,Birth Year
2017-05-29 18:36:27,2017-05-29 18:49:27,780,Columbus Dr & Randolph St,Federal St & Polk St,Subscriber,Male,1991.0
2017-06-12 19:00:33,2017-06-12 19:24:22,1429,Kingsbury St & Erie St,Orleans St & Merchandise Mart Plaza,Customer,,
2017-02-13 17:02:02,2017-02-13 17:20:10,1088,Canal St & Madison St,Paulina Ave & North Ave,Subscriber,Female,1982.0
```

by using pandas I need to load file.csv into a dataframe & find the most frequent hour when people start traveling despite of there isn't an hour column in this dataset!

```
import pandas as pd

filename = 'file.csv'

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

df['Start Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Time'])

df['hour'] = df['Start Time'].dt.hour

popular_hour = 
    
print('Most Frequent Start Hour:', popular_hour)
```

Comment: It is not clear what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You want the [mode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html).

```
df['Start Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Time'])

df['hour'] = df['Start Time'].dt.hour

popular_hours = df['hour'].mode()
```

Note that the returned series will contain multiple values in the case of a tie.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but if I need to find the most common hour (from 0 to 23)! should i use the mode ?

Comment: Yes, the code I have posted will give you the most common hour.

Comment: Has your question been answered?